# In which class, main () method calling is done?

Tags: java

As we know, every programme execution start from main () method in java. I want to know, in which class, sun microsystem calls the main () method, to start the execution of main () method?

Comment: Are you asking which class's `main` gets called, or where that call comes from?

Comment: it is a fine question - not all Java programs start with a main method - depending on configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run java application you specify main class as command line argument `java [options] class` or if you run it as `jar [options] -jar jarfile` then it is the class which is written inside this jar's MANFEST-MF as `Main-Class: class`

Answer (score 4):

JVM Specification may help here,

> [Java Virtual Machine Startup(§5.2)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.2) States that,
>   The Java Virtual Machine starts up by creating an initial class, which
>   is specified in an implementation-dependent manner, using the
>   **bootstrap class loader** [(§5.3.1)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.3.1). The Java Virtual Machine then links
>   the initial class, initializes it, and invokes the `public class method
>   void main(String[])`. The invocation of this method drives all further
>   execution. Execution of the Java Virtual Machine instructions
>   constituting the main method may cause linking (and consequently
>   creation) of additional classes and interfaces, as well as invocation
>   of additional methods.

Comment: Couldn't you get a reference to a chapter you reffered to?

Answer (score 1):

Set a breakpoint in your main() method, then run it, and check the call-stack.